# Basic HTML Button not changing text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a website showing off the power of CSS and JS. The CSS part seems to be working well, but the JS part isn't. I am trying to change the text, "Hello World," with a button press. However, whenever I press the button, it doesn't do anything.

I've tried fixing my  tag, trying different event handlers, putting the output in a function, subsequently removing it from the function, moving my script directly into the HTML, and using window.onload but none of it works.

```
<head>
        ><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        ><script type="text/javascript" src="../mybutton.js"></script>
    </head>
<p id="gold">Hello World</p>
<button type="button" id="jsClick">Don't Click<button>
<button type="button" id="jsHeal">Heal My World<button>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("jsClick") = function()>>{document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = "Please don't click";};
    document.getElementById("jsHeal") = function()>>{document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = "Hello World"};
}
```

My expected result would be to click the button and change the text of my paragraph. The actual output is that all the HTML and CSS loads as usual, but when I click, nothing happens. Edit: I have tried all the answers. I believe something is off with actually running JavaScript, as even programming the JavaScript directly in the HTML isn't working.

Comment: have you looked at your js console while loading this?

Comment: Side note, your closing button tage are wrong. And what's with the `>>` in `function()>>{`?

Comment: Not yet. I'll post when I get onto a computer that supports this

Comment: There's just... so much wrong here, syntactically. You're not properly closing your button tags, you're trying to assign functions directly to elements, you've got `>>` in the middle of a function definition for no apparent reasons, your paragraph's ID doesn't match the ID you're searching for... What browser doesn't have a JS console?

Comment: Add an onClick event to the buttons

Comment: I tried making my closing tags better, so at least now that's not messing up a little. error. I'm new, and I'm just getting the hang of formatting, so that wasn't in my original code.

Comment: @Tiago - I believe that is what he was (incorrectly) trying to do in the js... by setting the button elements equal to (an attempt at) a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues:

1. The IDs don't match; `Gold` is not `gold`
2. That's not how you initialize a function, remove the `>>`
3. You can't assign a value to the return value of a function (`document.getElementById("jsClick") =` doesn't work, you can't
   assign values this way); likely you want to set the `onclick`
   property to that function.
4. You didn't close the `<button>` tag.

Here's a working example of what you've provided:

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../mybutton.js"></script>
    </head>
<p id="gold">Hello World</p>
<button type="button" id="jsClick">Don't Click</button>
<button type="button" id="jsHeal">Heal My World</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("jsClick").onclick = function(){document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = "Please don't click";};
    document.getElementById("jsHeal").onclick = function(){document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = "Hello World"};
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added a function called change() which changes the paragraph text to hello world using an onClick event.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../mybutton.js"></script>
</head>


<p id="gold">Hello World</p>
<button type="button" id="jsClick">Don't Click<button>
<button type="button" onclick="change()" id="jsHeal">Heal My World<button>



<script>

function change()
{
document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML="Hello World";
}


</script>
```

Ps. lots of errors in your code should look into cleaning that up

Comment: Tried that. Fixed up errors, but I feel that something about the ```<script type="text/javascript" src="../mybutton.js"></script>``` isn;t working as a simple alert isn't appearing.

Comment: well i included <script> tags within this html file so you dont need to call that mybutton.js script

Comment: Javascript in general isn't working for some reason.

Comment: However, it can't be that my file is out of date, because CSS is updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" id="jsClick" onclick="changeMe()">Don't Click</button>

function changeMe() {
const myButton = document.getElementById("jsClick");
myButtoon.innerText = "Some random text"
}
```

Or you could select your element with DOM and add an event listener on it , a click event listener which triggers a function that does the above thing. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

ids and classes are case sensitive in HTML and Javascript, therefore `gold` is not equal to `Gold`